# Gracefully deleting files older than 30 days

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, find

I have a cache folder with minimum of 15000 files.

I tried this:

```
find cache* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

But this made my server load fly to the skies!

Is there any *faster/better* solution?

Or can I *limit speed or iterations* of this command?

Comment: If `cache*` expands to many files, you may want to try something like `find . -name 'cache*' -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like to use [`tmpwatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch) for these things, this is for the last time the file was modifiyed. It's simple and works well in many cases:

```
tmpwatch -m 720 /path/to/cache
```

For Ubuntu, check [`tmpreaper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/tmpreaper.8.html) instead.

If you want to check the last time the file was accessed than you use the following:

```
tmpwatch -a 720 /path/to/cache
```

You are not able to use tmpwatch -a on file systems mounted with noatime. you can still use -m

Comment: I'm using `Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS` and that command doesn't exists..

Comment: @Kristian Check for `tmpreaper` instead.

Comment: Any pitfalls when using these to manage filesystems mounted with noatime option?

Comment: @AnonymousLurker I have modifyed the answer for you

Answer (score 6):

You could avoid the spawning of a new process for each file by using

```
find cache* -mtime +30 -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running the above with nice:

```
nice -n 39 find cache* -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} ';'
```

That way the huge load will only appear if nothing else needs to run, otherwise the other processes will take precedence (if their niceness is lower than 19 i.e. the maximum).

Note that the argument to the -n option is added to the default niceness which varies between -20 and 19. I used 39 so that it will be *very* nice regardless of what original niceness there was.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by chiborg, the load is due to starting rm for every file found. I noticed the answer where `tmpwatch` is suggested as an alternative, which I'm sure works well. However, it is not necessary.

Find can run the command given to exec once, if you tell it to accumulate the found files into a list of arguments like so:

```
find /path -name "*.moo" -exec rm {} \+
```

This may sometimes fail to work because the argument list may grow larger (in bytes) than the maximum allowed by the shell (getconf ARG_MAX). This may be solved by xargs with the -L option.

consider this example:

```
$ echo 0 > /tmp/it; 
$ for i in {0..15000};do echo $i;done  |\
    xargs --no-run-if-empty -L 5000 ./tmp/xr.sh 
Iteration=0; running with 5000 arguments
Iteration=1; running with 5000 arguments
Iteration=2; running with 5000 arguments
Iteration=3; running with 1 arguments

$ cat tmp/xr.sh 
#!/bin/sh
IT=`cat /tmp/it`
echo Iteration=$IT\; running with $# arguments
let IT=IT+1
echo $IT > /tmp/it
```

So there is no need install extra software, all you need is in gnu-findutils:

```
find /path -mtime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 -L 5000 rm
```

Comment: some d00d thought it would be useful to add -print0 and -0 to find and xargs. Those arguments force their commands use the null char (\0) instead of a new-line (\n) to separate the arguments. This is helpful when the filename has spaces or new-lines in it.

Comment: (1) You don’t need to say `\+`; plain `+` is good enough.  (2) This won’t “fail to work because the argument list may grow large…”.  `find  … -exec … {} +` will do the same thing that `xargs` will do; it will run the command as many times as it needs to.  For example (as in your example), if you have between 15001 and 20000 files, `find` would run the `-exec`’d program (`rm`) four times.